# Refine ANN result precision

Tags: matlab, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I've a neural network in MATLAB that works well, but it should give me a result of 0 or 1, and it gets +/-0.05 error. (0.02, 0.97, 1.03, ...)

What should I change for the result to be more accurate?

```
p = [ 0 0 1 1; 0 1 0 1];
t = [0 1 1 0];    
net = feedforwardnet(2,'trainlm');
net.trainParam.goal = 0.01*var(t',1);
net.divideFcn = 'dividetrain';
[net,tr] = train(net,p,t);
a = net(p)
```